# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception error

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've read all the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" answers, but they don't seem to apply to my situation.

I've setting up a NSMutableDictionary like this...

```
  NSMutableDictionary *ObjectDynamic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pObject, @"pFObject",tObject, @"tFObject",nil];
```

and then at some later point in the code I'm trying to add in another object/key, with this...

```
[ObjectDynamic setObject:mySprite forKey:@"pSObject"];
```

But I'm getting an exception on that line, with the...

> -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Is it not possible to add in another key/value pair like that?

**Edit**

Simple mistake, I just was trying to make a NSDictionary rather than a NSMutableDictionary! Thanks for the answers anyway.

Comment: "I've read all the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" answers, but they don't seem to apply to my situation". Yes they do. They all say the same thing: this object is not an instance of the class you think it is. Believe the error message: it is telling you what class this object really is. Then try to understand how the object got to be the wrong class.

Comment: Yeah I can see that now, but was up till the early hours and just missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you initialize an immutable NSDictionary that doesn't have a `setObject:forKey:` method. Initialize a mutable one instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *ObjectDynamic = [NSMutableDictionary 
    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pObject, @"pFObject",tObject, @"tFObject",nil];
```

Since Xcode 4.4 you can also use the new dictionary literals to initialize immutable dictionaries very easily and then use `mutableCopy`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *objectDynamic = [@{@"pFObject" : pObject, 
                                        @"tFObject" : tObject} mutableCopy];
```

Note, that in Objective-C you should start variable names with lower case letters.

Comment: Ah right yeah, that's similar to how I would set up an object in AS3, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to change the content of a dictionary, you need to make `NSMutableDictionary`, not an immutable `NSDictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *ObjectDynamic = [NSMutableDictionary // <<== Here
    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pObject, @"pFObject",tObject, @"tFObject",nil
];
```

Comment: Oops, that will learn me not to be coding at 5am in the morning :)